# How to change the icon of file in MacOS in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, icons, alias

My program for MacOS is creating the alias to another file and I want this alias to have some designated icon. How can I do it with Objective-C, preferably in Cocoa?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `NSWorkspace`, which has a method for doing this:

```
//anImage is an NSImage object and
//pathToFile is a path string
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] setIcon:anImage forFile:pathToFile options:0];
```

This will save the icon data to the file's Resource Fork. These days Mac OS doesn't use actual resource forks, so the image is stored in an HFS extended attribute named `com.apple.ResourceFork`.

Extended attributes are filesystem metadata attached to a file. You can see the extended attributes attached to a file using [`xattr`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) and related commands.

Note that extended attributes are only guaranteed to be reliable on HFS+ file systems, if the file is located on a file server that doesn't support file metadata or on an external drive with a non-HFS file system, the icon may not be written.

Comment: Thanks. Looks incredibly simple. And what does this do actually to a file? Where does this method put the NSImage?

Comment: They are stored in the file's Resource Fork. These days Mac OS doesn't use actual resource forks, so the image is stored in an HFS extended attribute named `com.apple.ResourceFork`. Extended attributes are filesystem metadata attached to a file. You can see the extended attributes attached to a file using `xattr` and related commands.

Comment: OK. Thank you. You can post your solution in answer so that I can accept it.